# How can I search through a has_many association in Rails 3 (meta_where or railslogic?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, searchlogic, active-relation, meta-where

I have a model called UserHasMessages where:

```
belongs_to :message
belongs_to :user
```

And User.rb model is:

```
has_many :messages, :through => :user_has_messages
```

I want to find Users where the associated UserHasMessages has a Message_id of @message.id

I tried something like this (using searchlogic) but it didn't work, and did not know where to begin with meta_where:

```
User.user_has_message.message_id_is(@message.id).is_sender(false).last
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need searchlogic, MetaSearch, nor MetaWhere to make this happen:

```
User.joins(:user_has_messages).where(:user_has_messages => {:message_id => @message.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :messages

end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

You will also need a third table:

`messages_users`

And the migration will look something like

```
class CreateMessagesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :messages_users do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :message_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :messages_user
  end
end
```

Once that is setup, you can call

`@user.messages` or `@message.users` and setup some scopes on that.  This seems more appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are we also doing this under the Class or an object? Wouldn't it be more like @user.messages.find_by_id...? Maybe I'm missing something. Mid-afternoon naps are death to intellect

Comment: @jaredonnline -- thanks, I have to extract them because there is both a sender and a receiver for every message, and poeple may delete or change and sof roth so I need to abstract it to have two separate associations...will this work since it is a :has_many, :through?

Comment: It should work just fine. The :through part just tells rails to reach through another model to find the association. Try it in your console, and tell me if it works.

Comment: @jardeonline -- @user.messages displays an error, so I can't access messages.....

Comment: Ah. This is because your UserHasMessages model doesn't specify a has_many relationship of its own.  You know.. there's a paradigm for this, called a :has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. I think you should try that.  I will update my answer to show you what things should look like.

Comment: @jaredonline...thank you I will try it, i think I had to change my model because it was plural and causing troubles

Comment: hello how is has_many_and_belongs_to different from my belongs_to and has_many I am having some difficulty following to understand it thanks